# React-Native Image rendering on different android devices based on their DPI

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-android

I am new to react-native and trying to render images on different android device based on the DPI. Need Help with it.

Code for getting DPI of device is -

```
import {PixelRatio} from 'react-native';

const PDI = PixelRatio.get();
var localPath='';

if(PDI == 1){
    localPath = '../../assets/img/drawable-mdpi'
}
else if(PDI == 1.5){
    localPath = '../../assets/img/drawable-hdpi'
}
else if(PDI == 2){
    localPath = '../../assets/img/drawable-xhdpi'
}
else if(PDI == 3){
    localPath = '../../assets/img/drawable-xxhdpi'
}
else if(PDI == 3.5){
    localPath = '../../assets/img/drawable-xxxhdpi'
}
export {PDI, localPath};
```

And the react-native app.js file is -

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Image, StyleSheet, StatusBar, Alert} from 'react-native';
import { PDI, localPath } from '../../helper/device-size-android/GetDeviceSizeAndroid';

export default class TestImg extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
    }, 3000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <StatusBar
            barStyle = "dark-content"
         />
        <Image
          source={require(localPath + '/Splash.png')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence of if statements isn't going to work if **PixelRatio.get()** doesn't return one of the five values you single out, which are just typical values mentioned in the documentation that don't necessarily match the resolution of a particular phone. Compare PixelRatio.get() to intervals for robustness:

```
if(dpi<1.2){
  localPath = '../../assets/img/drawable-mdpi'
}else if(dpi<1.7){
  localPath = '../../assets/img/drawable-hdpi'
}else if(dpi<2.6){
  localPath = '../../assets/img/drawable-xhdpi'
}else if(dpi<3.2){
  localPath = '../../assets/img/drawable-xxhdpi'
}else {
  localPath = '../../assets/img/drawable-xxxhdpi'
}
```

Better yet, let the React Native Image component do the work with multiple images specified in the **source** property.